# Adding new view controller to custom Sliding ViewController with left, right and main view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have created a SlidingViewController which has a Main, Right, and Left view controllers. Now I want to add a new function/method that is called whenever one of the RightViewController's table view cell is clicked to switch the main view controller to what ever view controller is linked with that table view cell at indexpath.row. The new view controller should still be able to have this right and left view controller available. Anyone have any experience creating their own SlidingViewController or MenuViewController that can help out on how I should approach this? Any help will be gratefully appreciated. Thank you in advance.

SlidingViewController.h

```
@interface SlidingViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (retain) UIViewController *mainViewController;
@property (retain) UIViewController *leftViewController;
@property (retain) UIViewController *rightViewController;
@property (retain) NSNumber *leftSwipeEnabled;
@property (assign) BOOL leftDrawerVisible;
@property (retain) NSNumber *rightSwipeEnabled;
@property (assign) BOOL rightDrawerVisible;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil mainViewController:(UIViewController *)main leftViewController:(UIViewController *)left andRightViewController:(UIViewController *)right;
-(void)toggleLeftDrawer;
-(void)toggleRightDrawer;
@end
```

SlidingViewController.m

```
@implementation SlidingViewController
@synthesize mainViewController, leftViewController, rightViewController;
@synthesize leftDrawerVisible, rightDrawerVisible;
@synthesize leftSwipeEnabled, rightSwipeEnabled;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil mainViewController:(UIViewController *)main leftViewController:(UIViewController *)left andRightViewController:(UIViewController *)right
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
    {
        mainViewController = main;
        leftViewController = left;
        rightViewController = right;
        leftSwipeEnabled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        rightSwipeEnabled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addChildViewController:self.mainViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:[self.mainViewController view]];
    self.mainViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.mainViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2f;
    self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
    CGPathRef path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.mainViewController.view.bounds].CGPath;
    self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowPath = path;

    if(self.leftViewController != nil)
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
        leftSwipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        leftSwipeRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [self.mainViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipeRecognizer];
    }
    if(self.rightViewController != nil)
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
        rightSwipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        rightSwipeRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [self.mainViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeRecognizer];
    }



}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self layoutShadowWithDuration:0];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if(self.leftDrawerVisible)
        [self toggleLeftDrawer];
    else if(self.rightDrawerVisible)
        [self toggleRightDrawer];
}
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
-(void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if(recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight && [self.leftSwipeEnabled boolValue])
            [self toggleLeftDrawer];
        else if(recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft && [self.rightSwipeEnabled boolValue])
            [self toggleRightDrawer];
    }
}
-(void)toggleLeftDrawer
{
    if (self.rightDrawerVisible)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(self.leftDrawerVisible)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             self.mainViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.mainViewController.view.frame.size.width, self.mainViewController.view.frame.size.height);}
         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             [self.leftViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
             [self.leftViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
             [self.leftViewController removeFromParentViewController];
         }];
        self.leftDrawerVisible = NO;
        self.mainViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [self addChildViewController:self.leftViewController];
        [self.view insertSubview:[self.leftViewController view] belowSubview:[self.mainViewController view]];
        [self.leftViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        CGPathRef path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.mainViewController.view.bounds].CGPath;
        self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowPath = path;

        self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-3, 0);
        NSInteger width = 260;

        if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            width = 320;

        self.leftViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{ self.mainViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(width, 0, self.mainViewController.view.frame.size.width, self.mainViewController.view.frame.size.height); }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) { self.leftViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin; }];
        self.leftDrawerVisible = YES;
        self.mainViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
-(void)toggleRightDrawer
{
    if(self.leftDrawerVisible)
        return;

    if(self.rightDrawerVisible)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             self.mainViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.mainViewController.view.frame.size.width, self.mainViewController.view.frame.size.height);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [self.rightViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                             [self.rightViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
                             [self.rightViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                         }];
        self.rightDrawerVisible = NO;
        self.mainViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [self addChildViewController:self.rightViewController];
        [self.view insertSubview:[self.rightViewController view] belowSubview:[self.mainViewController view]];
        [self.rightViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        CGPathRef path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.mainViewController.view.bounds].CGPath;
        self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowPath = path;

        self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3, 0);

        NSInteger width = 260;
        if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            width = 320;
        self.rightViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width- width, 0, width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             self.mainViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(-width, 0, self.mainViewController.view.frame.size.width, self.mainViewController.view.frame.size.height);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             self.rightViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
                         }];
        self.rightDrawerVisible = YES;
        self.mainViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}

-(void) layoutShadowWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGPathRef oldShadowPath = self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowPath;

    if (oldShadowPath)
    {
        CFRetain(oldShadowPath);
    }

    // Update shadow path for the view
    CGPathRef path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.mainViewController.view.bounds].CGPath;
    self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowPath = path;

    // You would think setting duration to 0 would cause the animation added below to not animate. You would be wrong.
    if (duration != 0)
    {
        if (oldShadowPath)
        {
            [self.mainViewController.view.layer addAnimation:((^ {
                CABasicAnimation *transition = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowPath"];
                transition.fromValue = (__bridge id)oldShadowPath;
                transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
                transition.duration = duration;
                return transition;
            })()) forKey:@"transition"];
            CFRelease(oldShadowPath);
        }
        else
            if (oldShadowPath)
                CFRelease(oldShadowPath);
    }
    else
        if (oldShadowPath)
            CFRelease(oldShadowPath);
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self layoutShadowWithDuration:duration];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

Comment: you want to change content of MainViewController when RightView is clicked?

Comment: @iBhavesh I want to change the current MainView whenever a table view cell from the rightView is click. Basically swap out the view controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this by "Delegation Design Pattern"

In RightViewController.h add the following lines.

```
@protocol RightViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
   - (void)somethingClicked : (id)theObject;

@end

@interface RightViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<RightViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In RightViewController.m add the following lines.

```
- (void)somethingClicked : (id)theObject
{
   [_delegate somethingClicked:theObject];
}
```

Update MainViewController.h with the following code.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <RightViewControllerDelegate>
```

And Finally add the following code in the MainViewController.m

```
- (void)somethingClicked : (id)theObject
{
   // Perform Your Task
}
```